# Can we enhance evaporation rate with a vacuum pump?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

First, consider having water at 100C and 1atm and a **heat source**. If more heat added to water, we have more evaporation rate according to the following formula:

$$Q_{in}=m_{vapor}*h_{fg}$$

THEN

Consider having water at 100C and 1atm and a **vacuum pump**.
Can we change the water evaporation rate with the vacuum pump as we did change the evaporation rate with the heat source?
What are the formulas and calculations?

Thx

Comment: You should say that the heat source increases the temperature and the vacuum pump decreases the pressure. It's not at 100°C and 1 atm anymore. Both have increase the evaporation rate.

Comment: So as I understand we can increase evaporation rate buy boiling and also keeping the temperature at 100C--------But by using vacuum pump we can increase evaporation rate but the pressure of the vessel has changed and we can't keep the temperature constant at 100C-------By using heat source we can evaporate all the water in the vessel but by using vacuum pump we can't evaporate all water and some portion of water freeze due to temperature decrease

Comment: Water at 100 C and below 1 atm is steam.

Comment: @ahemmetter, If the pressure is constant (e.g., open to atmosphere), then you can not increase the temperature of boiling water by turning up the heat. Turning up the heat only increases the rate of boiling. Likewise, you can not maintain a constant temperature in boiling water if you reduce the pressure. Reducing the pressure will reduce the temperature.

Comment: @MENG, Re, "...some portion of water freeze..." If you reduce the pressure so quickly that some portion of the water freezes, that will _not_ stop it from evaporating. Only, if you want to be _strictly_ correct, you don't call it "evaporation" anymore. When a solid turns directly to gas without becoming liquid in between, the proper name for that is "[sublimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition))."

Comment: Thanks all. I wanted to calculate the amount of evaporation in a specific vacuum condition when there is no heat source...Consider some water in a closed reservoir which is connected to a vacuum pump, I wanted to know the rate of water evaporation.

Answer (score 2):

I dont quite see the purpose of the vacuum pump if you stay at the same 1 atm pressure. With a simple fan though you will accelerate evaporation because the air is never saturated

Comment: Re, "...air is never saturated." If water is _boiling_ in an open container, then the atmosphere above the liquid can not be saturated. "Boiling" means that bubbles of pure H2O gas (a.k.a., "steam") are forming on the bottom of the pan, rising to the surface, and releasing their content to the atmosphere. That process will continue, so long as heat continues to be added, even when there's nothing put pure H2O gas above the water

Answer (score 1):

As you drop the pressure, the boiling temperature drops. As the water boils the heat of vaporization comes from the water and the temperature drops. This should continue until the remaining water is frozen.  You may need to find out if the heat of vaporization is a function of temperature.

Comment: R.W. Bird, I know for a fact that the heat of vaporization IS a function of temperature.  As the boiling temperature goes down, the heat of vaporization goes up.  This makes sense because as water's boiling temperature approaches the critical temperature, the heat of vaporization approaches zero.